# How can I map values in two different arrays as properties on an equivalent array of objects?

Tags: ruby, arrays, object

I have two arrays:

```
a = [a1, ..., an]
b = [b1, ..., bn]
```

I want to create an array of Objects from these arrays where an object has fields `a` and `b`. So it would look like:

```
o = [o1, ..., on]
```

where `o1.a = a1` and `o1.b = b1` and `o2.a = a2` and `o2.b = b2` and so on.

Right now, I have:

```
Obj = Struct.new(:a, :b)
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
objs = []
// Is there a better way of doing the following or is it okay?
a.zip(b).each do |ai|
  objs << Obj.new(ai[0], ai[1])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a.zip(b).map { |args| Obj.new(*args) }
```

Per your edit:

```
a.zip(b).map { |(a, b)| Obj.new(a, b) }
```

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby 1.9, the following works:

```
a = (1..10).to_a
b = (11..20).to_a
o = Struct.new(:a, :b)

a.zip(b).map {|x, y| o.new(x, y) }

# => [#<struct a=1, b=11>, #<struct a=2, b=12> ... ]
```

You can just pass multiple parameters to the block, and the array that would be passed to it gets expanded into those parameters, just like `*args` or `a, b = [1, 11]` would do.